# the weirdest VI problem EVER

Tags: vim, vi, vim7.2

Ok, so I am trying to type the following in .cshrc file: **alias ls 'ls --color=auto'**.  I type one character at a tiem.

However, when I reach **--color=** i type **a** and cursor goes to the next line.

I checked the .vimrc file and didn't fine anything out of whack. I am using vim7.2

**EDIT**

I noticed it is only happens in the .cshrc file, and cursor starts blinking with **'** character.

I had "set mouse=a" set in .vimrc file

What is the problem?

Comment: do you have '=a' mapped to something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `textwidth` set?  If so it'll break your lines once they reach a certain length.  Inspect the value via

```
:set textwidth?
```

Set it to 0 to turn off hard line-wrapping.  Otherwise, do you have `a` mapped to something weird in insert mode?  Check

```
:imap a
```

to see if you do.

Comment: Even if that was the case, textwidth wouldn't break the word in half.

Comment: Does it only break at whitespace or can it be configured to break at non-word characters?  I haven't messed with `textwidth` and friends much.

Comment: after i type  '  as if alias ls ', the next character I type has a red background.

Comment: @Brian - Yes, true. But that is so rarely used in a custom manner, that anybody asking about it, is surely not using it (custom formatexpr function).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot test it now, but probably something wrong with the appropriate indent file for that filetype. Does it happen if you edit some other configuration file ?

Comment: I only noticed the problem in .cshrc file.